# preg_replace() No ending delimiter '.' found

Tags: plugins, php

I get this error:
`Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending delimiter '.' found in` but I can't figure out why

Here is the code:

```
foreach( $content as $item )
                {
                    $item = preg_replace( array('.',' '), array('-','-'), strtolower($item));
                    $replace = '<h4 id="'.utf8_decode($item).'">';
                    $phrase = preg_replace('/'.$tag.'/', $replace, $phrase, 1);
                }
```

Please also tell my WHY it doesn't work

Comment: @toscho. True. I was creating this within WordPress but I realize now that this indeed has nothing to do with WordPress. My Bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

`preg_replace` expects your first parameter to be a pattern.

Try a simple replace:

```
$item = str_replace( array('.',' '), array('-','-'), strtolower($item));
```

Comment: It's the simple things in life that make a difference. I thank you good sir.